# Retrofit call does executed but not trigger onResponse or onFailure

Tags: android, retrofit2

My call is executed but does not trigger the onResponse or onFailure method
The Json object that is returned has an image inside

This is the code in my interactor class

```
 private ExamApi initiateRetrofit() {
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    return retrofit.create(ExamApi.class);
}

public void getExamImage(String user, String token,String exId, String exDocId) {
    if (examApi == null) initiateRetrofit();
    Call<ResponseBody> call = examApi.getExamImage(user,token,exId,exDocId);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
            listener.onImageSuccess(response.body());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
            //TODO ONFAILURE
            //listener.onImageFailure();
           listener.onFailure();
        }
    });
}
```

this is my examApi

```
@GET("mobile/getExamImage")
Call<ResponseBody> getExamImage(
        @Query("user") String username,
        @Query("token") String token,
        @Query("exid") String exId,
        @Query("edid") String exDocId
);
```

Comment: what is class name of  your examApi

Comment: can you post your ResponseBody class too, then i can give you a working code

Comment: @YasinKaçmaz i use okhttp3.ResponseBody

Comment: @ThaneeStevens i posted a working example , you can take a look at

Comment: @ThaneeStevens and if you give me your example json response format i can help you easly

Comment: @YasinKaçmaz it just retruns an image

Comment: is your response like this: {image}@Thanee Stevens

Answer (score 1):

It is happening because you are making an asynchronous call on the retrofit. You are trying to capture the data even before the network call happens. This gives you a null result. Try Broadcasting the result using broadcast receiver or third party library like EventBus which will make your result available after the network call has happened.

Comment: Update: Adding to what I said, the broadcast receiver or the eventbus.post(<value>) must be called from inside the onResponse method of your retrofit call.